# Subquery slows my Query down

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle10g, query-optimization

**Given:**

- A View `DataView` with events. The events are stored with a timestamp `Inst` and data columns.
- The events fall into certain shifts, or intervals, starting each day at 06:00, 14:00 and 20:00.
- The View `DataView` holds several hundred events per shift with several years of backlog.
- The start timestamp of the current shift is stored in a table `CurrShift`. The column is with that information is labelled `StartTime` The table holds only one row with that information.

**Goal:**

Retrieve all events from the current shift, i.e. where `DataView.Inst >= CurrShift.StartTime`

**Solution but slow:**

```
SELECT *
FROM DataTable
WHERE Inst >= (SELECT StartTime FROM CurrShift);
```

The query runs longer than 30 minutes. That is not acceptable for the given application.

**Faster Query, but only for fixed date**

```
SELECT *
FROM Data_Table
WHERE Inst >= TO_DATE('19.07.2017 14:00:00');
```

This query runs in under 2.0 seconds. Fast enough for the given application.

**Question:**

1. Why is the first solution that slow compared to the second one? I guess the subquery is executed for each row of `DataView`, but hoped, the optimizer would figure that out.
2. Is there a more performant/better way to do the first query? It would be more convenient to use `CurrShift.StartTime` than calculation the timestamp in the application.

**@Robbie Toyota:** Yes, `Inst` and `StartTime` is definitely of type `date` in both tables.

**@dnoeth:** 1.) The subquery is returning only one row. The table holds only the start and end timestamps of the current shift plus its designation.
2.) I tried the MAX(..) anyway, without success.

**Explain Plans**
I executed explain plans as Robbie suggests and see a huge difference in the plans. But I do not know what to do with the info:

*Slow Query:*

```
SELECTED STATEMENT
  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER
    TABLE ACCESS FULL
    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER
      TABLE ACCESS FULL
      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER
        TABLE ACCESS FULL
  ...
```

*Fast Query:*

```
SELECTED STATEMENT
  NESTED LOOPS OUTER
    NESTED LOOPS OUTER
      NESTED LOOPS OUTER
...
```

with completely different referenced tables, and enormous CPU Coast for the hashing.

Comment: Is InstFROM a timestamp? I don't work in Oracle (I came here from the sql tag), but if InstFROM isn't the same datatype as Inst, the index on Inst might not get used.

Comment: A Scalar Subquery should return a single row (otherwise it will fail anyway), you probably need top apply MAX:  `WHERE Inst >= (SELECT MAX(Inst) FROM Time_Table)`. But I doubt this is what you actally want/need.

Comment: Well, you know that there's only a single row in `Time_Table`, the optimizer doesn't (unless it's `DUAL`). Try the MAX.

Comment: Have you utilized [`EXPLAIN PLAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm#PFGRF009) to check the query plan?

Comment: @RobbieToyota To be honest, that is still black magic for me. But see above in the edit

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Oracle's explain plan to be able to help much. A quick google search for "how to interpret an oracle explain plan" brings up a lot of good results, but it'll require you to spend a bit of time reading. But that reading time will be well spent - knowing how to debug is an important and underemphasized skill.

Comment: Posting eviscerated snippets of explain plans is a pointless exercise. They don't tell us anything so we can't use them to explain why your two queries have such different execution profiles. Performance tuning is **all about the details**.  If you can't post the details we need (for company confidential reasons or whatever) you should delete this question.

Comment: "The subquery is returning only one row. The table holds only the start and end timestamps of the current shift plus its designation"   It seems highly likely the optimizer disagrees and thinks that the sub-query returns lots of records. But you need to post fuller explain plans with cardinalities for us to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the subquery with the following:

```
DECLARE t Time_Table.Inst%TYPE;
SELECT Inst INTO t FROM Time_Table;
SELECT * FROM Data_Table WHERE Inst >= t;
```

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax. The question is tagged `[oracle]` so answers need to propose Oracle syntax.  Please be aware that `[sql]` just means generic SQL queries; questions relating to MS SQL Server are tagged `[sql-server]`

Comment: Updated. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This solved question 2.) but it is a bit of a messy approach. 
The TO_DATE() from the original *Fast Solution* could be substituted with SYSDATE without any noticeable performance loss.

**Recap:**

- The WHERE clause with SYSDATE runs reasonably fast
- It is hard to calculate the start-timestamp of the shift out of SYSDATE
- There is a Table providing that start-timestamp
- A WHERE clause using a subquery into that table is slow

**Solution:**

- Reduce the original data with a WHERE clause with SYSDATE to the current day
- Filter that subset with a WHERE clause and a subquery into the start-timestamp table is fast since it is only a fraction of the original data

**Code:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Data_Table
  WHERE Inst >= SYSDATE - 1;
)
WHERE Inst >= (SELECT StartTime FROM CurrShift);
```

The execution time is roughly 1.5 of the *Fast Solution* from the question.

**Concerning Question 1:**

I still do not know *why* the subquery is so slow. But I learned to interpret explain plans a bit better. The view is so complicated and deeply nested that it is hard work to start with explain plans there. Fun fact: Explain plan expected the query to run for 9 hours.